# Getting type information into `window.L`

Tags: typescript

We're using `leaflet` and have `@types/leaflet` installed.

But when we try to access `window.L` TypeScript says that `Property L does not exist on type 'Window'`.

We can do something like:

```
declare interface LeafletWindow extends Window {
  L: any
}

declare var window: LeafletWindow
```

But then `window.L` is `any`. Since `Leaflet` in `@types/leaflet` is a `namespace`, I cannot see an easy way of copying that information to `window.L`.

Answer (score -1):

`Property L does not exist on type 'Window'`

Create a file `globals.d.ts` with *only*:

```
import * as Leaflet from "leaflet";
declare global {
  interface Window {
    L: Leaflet.something
  }
}
```

## More

This and more patterns are covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html

Comment: But `window.L` is `Leaflet`. And `interface Window { L: Leaflet }` still gives an error that `Leaflet is not defined`. And the Leaflet namespace has a lot of definitions.